# Why svg stretches in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I believe this is a CSS question but I'm not sure. I have a website where in its mobile version, I am making the width of a div with an svg background 100% in CSS. In Chrome, the svg scales beautifully as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

However, when I go to Firefox, at the same screen width of 767 (media query is `max-width: 768px`) the svg ends up being stretched like in this screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT:** Here's my css:

    `width: 100% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    float: left;
    border: none !important;
    background: url('../assets/images/nra-image.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;`

Is this a thing with Firefox itself or can this be fixed in CSS without changing the 100% div width? Of course, asking because the point of using an svg over png/jpg is so I wouldn't have to worry about these types of issues. Guess I was wrong *shrug*.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what properties are being applied.

Comment: Added code. it's pretty simple.

Comment: Try `background-size:cover`

Comment: You should include the <svg> root element in the question too, the attributes on it may affect the outcome.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for the advice, but using cover doesn't work. It makes the svg look better, but it doesn't scale when resizing the window.

Comment: @MartavisP. We need to see the <svg> there a thousand attributes that could be the culprit. Plus is this inline, object, embed, iframe, or background? Nevermind, I see it's background.

Comment: @MartavisP. `background-size: contain` and remove any width and height attributes on <svg> as well as `viewBox` (don't remove `viewBox`, just make sure it doesn't have a width and height)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is to do with the code within the SVG itself.
make sure you are using the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute, and add preserveAspectRatio="meet" to it.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="meet">
    <!-- SVG CONTENT HERE -->
</svg>
```